# how can I use second sheet when I save/read csv file in javascript?

Tags: javascript, csv

```
// save to CSV
var csv = document.getElementById('a');
var csvContent = new Array();
csvContent.push(["COL_A","COL_B","COL_C"]);
var fileName = "file.csv";
var blob = new Blob(["\ufeff", csvContent]);
var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
csv.href = url;
csv.setAttribute('download', fileName);
csv.click();


// load CSV file
..
var lines = loadedCsvFile.split(/\r\n|\n/);
var result = [];
var headers = lines[0].split(",");

for(var i=0;i<lines.length;i++){
    var obj = {};
    var currentLine = lines[i].split(",");

    for(var j=0;j<headers.length;j++){
        obj[headers[j]] = currentLine[j];
    }

    result.push(obj);
}
```

this is my csv save/load code.

But, this code can use only first sheet.

how can I use second sheet?
I should be very grateful to you if you might help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you're talking about a CSV from Excel (or the likes) which 'had' multiple sheets?

CSVs don't use the sheet concept, they're are saved as a flat file. You will either need to save each sheet as a CSV individually and read separately, or concatenate the sheets.

Comment: Umm.. I should think another way. Thanks! :)